# Passing a URL to code in a helper method.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I created a Foo controller, and the Foo view allows users to enter and submit a URL. In my Foo helper I have a block of code which scrapes the URL entered by the user (Using nokogiri). How do I pass the url received from the user to the helper so that URL can be parsed and saved to the db? Should I set this up differently?

Comment: helpers are meant for view logic.  is there a reason you put the code in a helper and not the controller or a separate module/class?  If not, then yeah, you probably should set it up differently.

Answer (score 0):

> One way to archive this in Rails 3 is to call view_context inside the
>   controller to create a new ActionView instance for a controller, then
>   all helper methods will be available through this instance in the
>   controller.

```
view_context.scrape_url_method_in_helper
```

Or do this in FooController

```
include FooHelper
```

Also, read rik.vanmechelen's comment below.

Comment: indeed, but maybe he should not make this a helper method but a method in his controller or place it in the lib directory and require the file.